# AllowAnonymous attribute not applied, controller action still requires login

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, security, umbraco

I have an entire site built on Umbraco that needs to restrict access to all pages. The only exception is a landing page, and a logout confirmation page.

To restrict access to only signed in users, I have the following in the web.config:

```
<deny users="?"/>
```

Then, to allow anonymous users on the logout confirmation page, I have the following attribute at the beginning of the LoggedOut controller method:

```
[Umbraco.Web.WebApi.MemberAuthorize(AllowAll = true)]
public ActionResult LoggedOut()
{
    var viewModel = new LogoutSuccessViewModel();
    viewModel.Message = "Hello";
    return View("LogoutSuccess", viewModel);
}
```

I have also tried the more standard MVC way of using:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
```

Either way, when I logout successfully, the application forwards me to the logout confirmation, and then it requires I login to see it, so it forwards me again to the login page. :(

How can I allow anonymous users?

Comment: Don't know if this is relevant, but this is a surface controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `<deny users="?"/>` in your `web.config` file. That means anonymous users do not have access to your application. So, of course `[AllowAnonymous]` does not work.

You need to allow anonymous access to the logout path in your `web.config` file like this:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="Path to your LoggedOut Action">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

But, why do you want to give anonymous access to the logout page? That does not make any sense.